# Interior point of a cone

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading the book Operator Inequalitis by Johann Schroder. I came across the following and I have some difficuly in understanding it.

Let $(X, \leq)$ be an ordered linear space. A relation $u \succ 0$ is defined as follows :

> $u \succ 0$  if and only if for each $v \in X$ there exists a number $n$ with $ nu + v \geq 0$

I can intuitively feel that this order relation has some relations with the interior of the cone. And it is given that for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, the interior(with respect to the usual topology) of the cone $\{x=(x_{1},...,x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:x_{i} \geq 0\}$ is precisely the set $\{u\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: u \succ 0\}$. But I am not able to understand how is this true and I wonder is there a relation between the set $\{u\in X: u \succ 0\}$ and the interior of the corresponding cone for a generel ordered normed linear space $X$.

Comment: I tried using the usual definition of interior points ($x \in int A$ iff there exists  $\epsilon >0$ such that the ball $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq A$ )to prove it. But I do not get it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_interior